# Free monoidal and free Markov categories

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

I hope this question is not too vague. I suppose one way to think about all the paths from one vertex to another within graph is to think about the free functor from graphs to categories, which is the left adjoint of the forgetful functor. The free functor sends a graph to a category with $\text{Hom} (A,B)$ corresponding the set of paths from vertex $A$ to vertex $B$ in the graph. My question is, can one do something similar for more structured categories. In particular, I am interested in Markov categories (but I would be happy if someone could give me insight, just for the case of monoidal categories). So is there a free/forgetful relationship between the category of Markov categories (or the category of monoidal categories), and some other category (analogous to the graph-category example above). The reason I ask is that I want to think about all of the ways to form arrows between two objects within a Markov category by composing together a certain set of `primitive arrows' (and using the special arrows that come from the Markov category or monoidal category structure to help to build the paths).